# How can I successfully create an infinitely scrolling background?

Tags: python, kivy

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Background(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Background, self).__init__(**kw)

        with self.canvas:
            texture = CoreImage('space.png').texture
            texture.wrap = 'repeat'
            self.rect_1 = Rectangle(texture=texture, size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.txupdate, 0)

    def txupdate(self, *l):
        t = Clock.get_boottime()
        self.rect_1.tex_coords = -(t * 0.001), 0, -(t * 0.001 + 10), 0,  -(t * 0.001 + 10), -10, -(t * 0.001), -10


class CosmicPolygons(App):
    def build(self):
        return Background(size=Window.size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CosmicPolygons().run()
```

I've tried many different ways and attempts in order to create a scrolling background in Kivy. This was the best method I could find as it was the only one that didn't crash. But I'm pretty sure it's still outdated as it did not work as intended, in addition to distorting my png greatly.

If anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Image of current app:

[image: current app]

Space.png:

[image: space.png]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that just creates a list of `Images` and moves them across the screen:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window

class BgImage(Image):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<BgImage>:
    source: 'stars.png'
    allow_stretch: True
    size_hint: None, 1
    width: self.image_ratio * self.height
''')


class Background(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Background, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.deltax = 3  # sets speed of background movement
        self.bg_images = []  # list of Images that form the background
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_up_bg)

    def set_up_bg(self, dt):
        # create BgImages and position them to fill the Background
        self.start_x = None
        pos_x = -1
        while pos_x < self.width:
            img = BgImage()
            if self.start_x is None:
                # starting position of first Image is just off screen
                self.start_x = -self.height * img.image_ratio
                pos_x = self.start_x
            img.pos = (pos_x, 0)
            self.bg_images.append(img)
            self.add_widget(img)

            # calculate starting position of next Image by adding its width
            pos_x += self.height * img.image_ratio

        # start moving the background
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/30.0)

    def update(self, dt):
        for img in self.bg_images:
            img.x += self.deltax
            if img.x > self.width:
                # this Image is off screen, move it back to starting position
                img.x = self.start_x


class CosmicPolygons(App):
    def build(self):
        return Background(size=Window.size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CosmicPolygons().run()
```